# Remove annotation from MKMapView which is in another view

Tags: iphone, delegates, mkmapview, uiapplicationdelegate

I have two views.  The first is a `MKMapView` with some annotations.  Clicking a `UIButton` pushes a second view on the stack.  This has a `UITableView` with a list of annotations which correspond to the map annotations.  So, when you click the delete button, how can I call my `MKMapView` which is in another view, so that I can remove the annotation.  My `MKMapView` is declared in my app delegate, as well as my current class.  I am trying to use the following, but it is not working:

```
RideAppDelegate *appDelegate = (RideAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
Annotation *ano;
CLLocationCoordinate2D anoPoint;
anoPoint.latitude = [[eventToDelete valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
anoPoint.longitude = [[eventToDelete valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
ano = [[[Annotation alloc] init] autorelease];
ano.coordinate = anoPoint;
[appDelegate.ridesMap removeAnnotation: ano];
[appDelegate release];
```

I must be trying to access the `MKMapView` of my other view incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ridesMap must be the MKMapView which must be an ivar of appDelegate. Is it a property with (retain)? Is it created and assigned with `self.ridesMap = [[MKMapView alloc] init]` or similar?
- You are sure Annotation follows MKAnnotation protocol?

(why release the appDelegate? You don't own or retain it.)

Comment: Yes, I am sure that Annotation follows MKAnnotation protocol, as I am able to create annotations using that.  ridesMap is a property with retain.  Where should I create it and alloc MKMapView like you showed above?

Comment: If it needs to be a property in your appDelegate, probably you should create it in applicationDidFinishLaunching. If it's not a live object you can't use a method on it.